# Sending email via mail function in php on Linux server

Tags: php

Is there a way I can send emails from PHP using smtp auth? It appears my host doesn't allow you to send email without auth using the mail function in php.

I can't use pear because i don't think they support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) instead. They're far more robust, and easier to use than PHP's `mail()` function, particularly if you want to do HTML mail and/or attachments.